# stored procedures with python pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server-2005

I have this Stored procedure on my sql server :

```
[InsertRecord] @param1 varchar(10), @Param2 varchar(50),@Param3 varchar(10)=NULL, 

@Param4 datetime = NULL AS BEGIN
```

When I update it with the following code :

```
   connenction = pymssql.connect (host=host1,user=user1,password=password1,database=database1)
  curser = connection.cursor() 

  my_query="exec InsertRecord '%s','%s','%s','%s'" %(var1,var2,var3,var4)
  print my_query
  cur.execute(my_query)
```

I didn't get any sentax error and the stored procedure not updated on my DB

but when i run the my_query string from the sql managment studio the query ran as it should be .
could someone provide what could be the problem with this code and how should i run this stored procedure with pymssql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your fiance said - you have commitment issues!

`connection.commit()`